# Take a screenshot of an entire webpage in Opera

Tags: opera, screenshot, webpage

Is there some tool within Opera, or possibly an add-on, which will let me take a screenshot of an entire web page?  I usually use [Screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146/) to do this with Firefox, but in this situation I want a screenshot of the page as Opera renders it (because I want to show the page as rendered with HTML5 form controls like date and time).

I am currently using Opera 10.60 x86_64 on Fedora 12, so solutions that work in browser would be preferable rather than external programs.

Comment: Another option would be using Opera's rendering engine in firefox using some extension and then use screengrab. e.g. IE Tabs extension renders pages in FF as they would in IE.

Comment: @tumchaaditya Know of an extension that can use Opera's rendering engine in Firefox?

Answer (score 4):

I purchased [ashampoo Snap 3](http://www2.ashampoo.com/webcache/html/1/product_2_0324___USD.htm) for this very reason.

After purchasing I did become aware of the following:

- [ScreenGrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146/) addon for Firefox
- [WebShot](http://websitescreenshots.com/)
- [Pearl Crescent Page Saver](http://pearlcrescent.com/products/pagesaver/) (Firefox Addon)
- [KHTML2PNG](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125951/command-line-program-to-create-website-screenshots-on-linux
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image

There maybe more out there that are paid and/or free but this small list should get you started. I am sorry none of these integrate with Opera like you require but you may have to just adjust your workflow for what you require.

Update: I jumped to a conclusion about you O/S and for that I am sorry! List updated with more specific to your needs and O/S

Comment: I can already get screenshots on Linux, and I mentioned in the question I am already using Screengrab in Firefox, so my workflow is fine.  What I need, in this particular case, is a shot of the entire page as it is rendered by Opera because it is the only browser which has implemented UI for the new HTML5 forms controls.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: There is now an extension that allows taking a screenshot of an entire webpage in Opera: [Screenshoter](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/screenshoter/?display=en) (requires Opera 12.10+).

---

With the current stable build, there is no function or extension API that allows this. But there are now Opera developmental builds which contain a screenshot API, so we may see a screenshot extension or native function for Opera in the near future:

- [Desktop build with new extension APIs: Screenshot  Resource Loader and URL Filter](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/new-extension-apis-screenshot-resource-loader-url-filter/)
- [Screenshot API](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/extensions-api-screenshot/)
- [Attention developers: Screenshot APIs and an updated URL Filter API are ready for testing](http://my.opera.com/addons/blog/2012/05/16/attention-developers-screenshot-apis-and-an-updated-url-filter-api-are-ready-fo)

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you prefer an in browser feature, but I don't use Opera so I can only suggest external methods.

If you use windows 7 the snipping tool (which comes free with every version of 7 I believe, located under accessories) can be used to drag and select any part of the screen (in your case just the browser window) and later edited in it's simple editing panel. It's a very tiny program and takes about 2 minutes to learn to use, literally.

Or you could always take a screen shot by hitting the print screen button on your keyboard and croup out everything other than the browser window in a graphics editing program like Photoshop, Fireworks or even the primitive MS Paint, such a crop job takes no graphics editing experience as it's just a matter of selecting the crop tool, dragging it over the area in the image that you want to keep and double clicking the mouse and saving the result.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have been more clear in the question.  Hitting print screen or any of those snipping type tools only gives you what's currently visible in the window, I want the entire web page.

Answer (score -1):

Another external suggestion is Jing (http://jingproject.com/), a free capture tool for Windows and Mac OS X.  It will grab 'natural' areas in windows such as the whole window, the tabs, or the client area.  It can also be used to drag to highlight a specific area and capture just it.  It can also capture movies with audio.