# How can you take a screenshot of an entire webpage?

Tags: screenshot, webpage

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Take a screenshot of an entire webpage](https://superuser.com/questions/149190/take-a-screenshot-of-an-entire-webpage)
>   [Take a high resolution screenshot of a website](https://superuser.com/questions/30858/take-a-high-resolution-screenshot-of-a-website)

How can you take a screenshot of an entire webpage?

This would ignore the scroll bars (if any) and generate a image of the whole web page.

See this example:

[image]

Ideally this would be for Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Doh, it is a dupe, how did I miss -- voting to close my own question (this a new one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146/) for Firefox may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [**Hypersnap-DX**](http://www.hyperionics.com/).  It's not free, but the trial version should do if you just need it for the odd occasion.

[image: Hypersnap-DX]

Answer (score 0):

[SnagIt](http://download.cnet.com/Snagit/3000-2192_4-10004813.html)!

Will auto scroll down the page to.