# What is the best way to test a webpage on higher resolution than your current screen's resolutions?

Tags: windows, display, resolution, website

I'm making a responsive website where I need to test my webpage's css, html, javascript rendering on 2400px resolution while my screen is only 1900px.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you take a screenshot of an entire webpage?](http://superuser.com/questions/216823/how-can-you-take-a-screenshot-of-an-entire-webpage)

Comment: You do realize that you can resize browser windows beyond your screen resolution on most systems? Just move them halfway out of the screen and then resize the border that's now in the middle of the screen. It's useless for actual use, but will suffice for testing. [This screenshot of the complete window](http://i.stack.imgur.com/s7G3O.png) was taken on OS X with 1680x150 screen resolution.

Comment: @DanielBeck - strange i'm trying same on my Chomre (Windows) but it not stretching beyond my current screen

Comment: [It's really a problem with your OS trying to outsmart you then](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BIfav.png). Could reproduce with Safari on Windows 7.

Comment: Mine is Windows 7 too

Comment: Some video cards will expand beyond the resolution of the actual monitor, to the screen buffer capability of the video display. In XP  I could easily get to that res with the ATI card.  Then the screen becomes a scrolling screen, allowing for a full simulation of a 2400 type screen.  You could check for that in windows own resolution settings, or in the video cards own settings utility.  Same thing isnt working out too well in windows 7 :-(  Gotta be a way to fix that.

Comment: Since we already are suggesting web sites for this, does it work with http://resizemybrowser.com/ ?

Comment: @DanielBeck - no it doesn't go beyond my screen even i created a size of 2500px

Answer (score 5):

If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> in recent versions of Firefox, you'll enter [Responsive Design View](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View), which can resize the browser viewport to be larger than the actual screen size. You can also take screenshots and simulate touch events from FF 26 onwards.

[[image: Screenshot of RDV]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPDFS.png)

You might find it easier to resize after you make the window smaller - you can drag the sizers further in one go. Or just enter a custom preset from the dropdown.

Comment: Is there an api for this option ? For enabling it via js code injected either from website or from inside an addon?

Comment: @KamalReddy I don't think you'd be able to do so from within the content context (website), but it should be possible from the chrome context (addon). Well, [in the future](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/DevToolsAPI) anyway. Perhaps you can simulate the Ctrl+Shift+M?

Answer (score 4):

In Chrome browser:

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd>. This will open DevTools.
2. Click a settings icon in the lower right corner. This will open DevTools Settings.
3. Go to Overrides on the left menu.
4. Check Enable and Device metrics.
5. Type in the Screen resolution

I always use it, it's really convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [website](http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php) it let you test your web page with any screen resolution
it let you choose from a preset resolutions or enter your custom resolution.
hope you find these lines helpful.

Comment: Being blocked by our proxy server. Is that a pointer to another site, or is that PHP page the actual page of the tool?

Comment: the PHP page that I've added here is the actual page of the tool

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably more suited for [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) but I'll take a stab at it and suggest [ViewLikeUs](http://viewlike.us/) which

> allows you to check out how your website looks in the most popular resolution formats.

Comment: it has only 1920 max

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom screen resolution in your video card's control panel.

Comment: Resolutions greater than supported by the screen? Could you provide more details how to configure this and what it looks like?

Comment: @DanielBeck This YouTube tutorial [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlERjmkBoHg) is for nVidia cards. Fairly similar for ATI/AMD.

Comment: @ElGenieben That video explicitly warns at 0:39 that you could damage your display by setting a resolution that's too high.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this online resolution tester, it offers variety of different resolutions to test your site with, just enter the url of your site, select a resolution and check it out.

http://www.webestools.com/resolution-tester-screen-size-page-design-test-screen-resolution-website-online-display.html

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the addon for Chrome: [Resolution tester](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resolution-test/idhfcdbheobinplaamokffboaccidbal?hl=en) that supports custom resolutions :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the zoom on your browser, when you zoom out, essentially your window size is reporting a bigger and bigger width to your application.

[example jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ERRy/), just click on the button, see the width it's reporting, then zoom out a little and click the same button-- it'll report a larger size.

Answer (score 0):

Try the custom resolution settings in the device emulator in Google Chrome. It gives you more control than using the browser's zoom functionality.

Enable the device emulator and check the 'zoom to fit' option.

Manually enter resolutions up to 9999px wide (or drag the edges of the emulated screen. The emulated resolution will be scaled to fit in your own viewport.

You can keep the resolution height low actually as you will be able to scroll down anyway. This way you can keep the inspector open too. A great workflow for web development!