# Is there any program to printscreen a webpage?

Tags: print-screen

I'm doing a lot of printscreening of a website at the moment for documentation.

I usually just use the snipping tool that comes standard with Windows 7 but if the page is longer than the length of the page, it's actually quite awkward.

I have to either make the text really small to capture it all or print screen multiple times and stitch it together.

Is there an existing way or new app that'll allow me to print screen a webpage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take a high resolution screenshot of a website](http://superuser.com/questions/30858/take-a-high-resolution-screenshot-of-a-website), [Take a screenshot of an entire webpage in Opera](http://superuser.com/questions/149190/take-a-screenshot-of-an-entire-webpage-in-opera), [How can you take a screenshot of an entire webpage?](http://superuser.com/questions/216823/how-can-you-take-a-screenshot-of-an-entire-webpage) and many more screenshot related questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using chrome there's an extension available called "awesome screenshot" [1].

[1] https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce?hl=en

Comment: it is available for firefox too. Several ext for chrome to choose from:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/screen%20capture?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Various browser extensions/addons can do this for you. Here are those with the most users (the most popular) for Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox:

**Google Chrome**: [Screen Capture (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce)

**Mozilla Firefox**: [Webpage Screenshot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/)

Comment: He means this one: <https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg?hl=en> I think.

Comment: Oops, sorry! Yeah, I messed up because Superuser caught my first submit attempt (I tried posting more my 2 allowed links). Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Fireshot which is available for Chrome/Firefox/IE or Windows Vista/7 Snipping Tool both do quite well for this.

Fireshot will allow you to do a selection on however much of the page you want, not just visible, so if you only wanted the left menu that continued for two browser viewport heights, you can just click and drag it. The screen scrolls till you've found your bottommost diagonal corner of the selection rectangle. Save to clipboard, file of preference, pdf, etc.